# X3DOM TwoSidedMaterial does not work

Tags: javascript, x3dom

I am trying to put a TwoSidedMaterial on a plane in order for both sides to be shown. However, I can't get it to work, all I get is an empty scene and an error in the console: `TypeError: mat._vf.diffuseColor is undefined`

```
<body>
  <x3d width='600px' height='400px'>
    <scene>
      <shape>
        <appearance>
          <twosidedmaterial diffuseColor="1,0,0"></twosidedmaterial>
        </appearance>
        <plane></plane>
      </shape>
    </scene>
  </x3d>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong? (I am using Firefox v30.0 on linux.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what has changed, but suddenly, embarrassingly, things work as I expected them to.